# typescript error: Property 'log' does not exist on type {...} - Console.log()

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors

I have typescript files that are compiled into JavaScript files which ultimately run within a web application. My ultimate aim is to have timers in these compiled JavaScript files so I can log how long it's taking for blocks of code to execute. In order to do this, I need to learn how to output data to a log file, and this (at its most basic) requires me to have some sort of `Console.log('Whatever I want to log')` statement in my JavaScript. I'm starting off small and then building off the baby steps.

Since the typescript is compiled into JavaScript, I have to put any logging and timer code into the typescript first so that it will compile to JavaScript.

I tried putting `Console.log("...")` into the typescript so that it would compile to the JavaScript and ultimately output "..." when the JS code was run. But during compiling, I got an error:

`"Property 'log' does not exist on type '{ new (): Console; prototype: Console; }'"`

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can I do to make sure that any "javascript code" that I have to first write in typescript gets compiled correctly?

Obviously, I'm a complete newbie with any of this but my task remains nonetheless.

Comment: `console` should be lowercase, eg: `console.log("Something")`, **not** `Console.log("Something")`.

Comment: @CRice well don't I feel silly. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`Console.log("...")` should be `console.log("...")` (lowercase `c`). This is TypeScript helping you preventing a mistake.